# Header only library: use class defined later on in the header

Tags: c++

I am creating a header-only library. In this library I would like to already use a class that is defined later in the header. For example:

```
class A {
public:
  int i;

  A(int x) : i(x) {};

  B func(B inp) {
    B out(i*inp.j);
    return out;
  };
};

class B {
public:
  int j;

  B(int x) : j(x) {};

  A other(A inp) {
    A out(j*inp.i);
    return out;
  };
};
```

Naturally my compiler does not like this. It produces the first error on the line on which `func` is defined:

```
 error: unknown type name 'B'
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: Declare B before A!?

Comment: @Borgleader. Yes of course... But I want to do the same thing vice versa, i.e. use `A` in `B`

Comment: @TomdeGeus That requirement is not present in your question... Only A uses B in it.

Comment: @Borgleader You are right, I should have addressed this more clearly. I have edited the question.

Comment: Why don't you update the code instead of amending the question? This should be rather trivial. In doing so you can also strip the irrelevant parts (e.g. member function `A::A(int inp)` does not contribute to the issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a *reference* or *pointer* requires a *declaration* of the corresponding type. Using an object (instance) or any member requires the full *definition* or the corresponding type. A declaration is

```
class A;   // declares: there is a class called 'A'
```

while a definition is

```
class A {  // (re-)declares A and defines its layout and members
   /* details */
};
```

A declaration can precede a definition (but does not have to for the definition to be valid). This immediately gives the following solution.

1. Order the class *definitions* such that later defined classes only use *objects* and *members* of earlier defined class in their *interface*. For example

   ```
   class A {
     int i;
   public:
     A(int x) : i(x) {}
   };

   class B {
     A a;                // object of type A: okay, since A is defined
   public:
     B(int i) : a(i) {}
     int foo() const {
       return a.i;       // member of a: okay, since A::i is defined
     }
   };
   ```
2. Classes of which *references* or *pointers* are used in any earlier declared class can be **forward declared** (not *defined*) before any class *definition*. For example

   ```
   class B;              // forward declaration of B

   class A {
     int i;
   public:
     A(int x) : i(x) {}
     A(B*);              // pointer to B okay, since B is declared
                         // cannot define A::A(B*): it depends on definition of B
   };

   class B {
     int x;
     A a;                // object of type A: okay, since A is defined
   public:
     B(int i) : x(i+i), a(i) {}
     B() : a(this);
   }
   ```
3. Define any implementation details that depend on the definition of classes not known at the time of declaration.

   ```
   inline A::A(B*b)      // either inline or in a source file
     : i(b->x/2)         // using member B::x okay: B is defined
   ```

Comment: if you don't add `inline` to the definition as mentioned in the other answer you'd get linker errors if the header was included in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to forward declare the class `B`, and move the function definition out of the class.

Normally one would put the definition in a source file, but since it's a header-only library you can instead mark the function definition as `inline` and you can put it inside the header file itself, but after the definition of the `B` class of course.

Another and more simpler way, if `B` doesn't depend on `A`, is to move the definition of `B` to be *above* the definition of `A` in the header file.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying that this would be the way to go, but if a little misuse of templates is fine with you, you could do something like this (same example but removed irrelevant stuff and added B using A as you mentioned):

```
template <typename X>
struct A {
  X func(X inp) { return X(/*...*/); }
};

struct B {
public:
    A<B> func(A<B> inp) { return A<B>(); }
};
```

As I said, I wouldnt really do this just to avoid a forward declaration. On the other hand, you should reconsider if you really need the circular dependency. If two classes depend too much on each other, you cant touch one without having to check if the other didnt break. Thats not nice and if possible I would avoid it.